# No value given for one or more required parameters. Update Statement in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Where is the problem in this code?

```
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("update SalesDates set Name=@name1,Weghit=@weghit1,
                                        Price=@price1,PriceUnloaded=@PriceUnloaded1,Total=@total1,
                                        Totalprice=@Totalprice1,Unloadedtotal=@Unloadedtotal1 ,
                                        Wegiht_bill_no=@Wegiht_bill_no1,Dates_types=@Dates_types1,
                                        Store=@Store1 where ID=id2", conn)

cmd.Parameters.Add("@name1", OleDb.OleDbType.Char).Value = name1
cmd.Parameters.Add("@weghit1", OleDb.OleDbType.Decimal).Value = weghit1
cmd.Parameters.Add("@price1", OleDb.OleDbType.Decimal).Value = price1
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PriceUnloaded1", OleDb.OleDbType.Decimal).Value = PriceUnloaded1
cmd.Parameters.Add("@total1", OleDb.OleDbType.Decimal).Value = total1
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Totalprice1", OleDb.OleDbType.Decimal).Value = Totalprice1
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Unloadedtotal1", OleDb.OleDbType.Decimal).Value = Unloadedtotal1
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Dates_types1", OleDb.OleDbType.Char).Value = Dates_types1
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Wegiht_bill_no1", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = Wegiht_bill_no1
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Store1", OleDb.OleDbType.Char).Value = Store1

conn.Open()

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
cmd = Nothing
```

When executing this code in Access, everything is good. But when I use it in VB.Net, I get the message:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: I would keep the parameters in the same order, just in case. But I think there's something weird with ID=id2, maybe id2 is supposed to be a parameter?

Comment: ID=id2 i make it read from data grid